# How to prevent livedata returning null to the binding adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a spinner in my xml layout which sets a attribute named sourceData

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <import type="com.lionosur.dailyexpenses.database.Entity.Source"/>
        <import type="java.util.List"/>
        <import type="android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData"/>
        <variable name="createExpenseViewModel" type="com.lionosur.dailyexpenses.viewModels.MainViewModel"/>

    </data>
    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/expense_category"
            app:sourceData="@{createExpenseViewModel.getAllSourceItems(1)}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
    />
```

the method createExpenseViewModel.getAllSourceItems(1) returns the variable of type **LiveData<List<Source>>** , i have written a binding adapter to bind the list returned by that method in to spinner

```
class AddExpenseAdapter {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("app:sourceData")
        fun setSourceData(spinner: Spinner, sourceList: List<Source>?) {

            val categoryItems = ArrayList<String>()

            if (sourceList != null) {
                categoryItems.addAll(sourceList.map { it.sourceName })
            }
            val spinnerAdapter =
                ArrayAdapter<String>(spinner.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categoryItems)


            spinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter


        }
    }
}
```

i have implemented binding in my activity as following

```
 lateinit var binding: ActivityCreateExpenseBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_create_expense)


        val mainViewModel = DaggerExpenseComponent.builder()
            .setContext(this)
            .build()
            .getExpenseViewModel()

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
        binding.createExpenseViewModel = mainViewModel

    }
```

but my method  **fun setSourceData(spinner: Spinner, sourceList: List?)** sourceList always receives null value, i am just confused why livedata returns null in to a binding adapter, if i observe the same viewmodel method with in the activity then i can see the items, but using data binding i can only get null values to my binding adapter

Comment: I am not sure abt this, but would you try changing `sourceList: List<Source>?` to `sourceList: LiveData<List<Source>>?` also change `app:sourceData` to `sourceData` in the same file

Comment: it didnt work either

Comment: app namespace will be automatically ignored by annotation processor